# C# webcontrol - catch errors

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I use webcontrol to embed youtube iframe. I tried to use `webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` but It's still not work in this case

[image]

i need to find a way to detect that this error happens and restart my app. But I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Sorry about my English. thanks.

Comment: May I ask, what document mode you are running your web browser control in?  You may be able to modify the registry and make that error not happen in the first place.

Comment: By default the web browser control uses the document mode of 7 which has it use the IE7 rendering engine.  This can cause lots of script errors and slow scripts on websites using modern standards.

Comment: Is there any way to catch this error and restart the computer?

Comment: No you cannot catch the errors. You could modify the registry for the web browser control to be able to use a higher document mode which would likely stop the errors from happening in the first place.

Comment: I want to use Edge browser, so i changed the registry. And this problem happens. How to change the registry?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)

Comment: Can you let me know which key, and the value that i need to change? The documents seems long. Thank a lot.